# PHPExcel - Read data from specific columns by header name?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have a project where the client uploads several XLS files and I need to grab the data only from the columns that he has named with specific headers (where header = data in first row). Sometimes they aren't even in the same order or they might be spread across the worksheet so I cant use a range.

I was thinking of creating an array with the column names I want to read, scan the worksheet and find the column ids and start reading the worksheet with getCellByColumnAndRow(). 
However, I feel that this might be like reinventing the wheel so I thought I'd ask if there are ready methods I'm unaware of.

Comment: You're probably going to want to use a library to do this. Try this out: [PHP-ExcelReader](http://phpexcelreader.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I'm already using PHPExcel.

Comment: Did you look through the documentation on the website for a solution to your problem?

Comment: There is no method built into PHPExcel unless your spreadsheet uses Named Ranges, because this isn't an inate featute of MS EXcel or of any other spreadsheet program - creating a column lookup table by scanning the first row is your best option

Comment: You mean, to first set A->Surname, B->Name, C->email etc and then process the data?

Comment: Something along those lines... get an array of his column names; read the first row of the worksheet as an indexed array (using rangeToArray(), do an array_intersect with the list of column names, then get the keys, and that will give you a list of columns to read ('A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'G') etc. Then you can loop through each row using rangeToArray() and array_intersect to get the required columns from that row

Comment: That's pretty much what I was thinking about as the logic, just didnt know all the functions that are available. Thank you for now, I will come back with more questions on the way.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?? I have a similar case. Could you please post code if yes.